# change form field value with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function up(d,mul)
{
alert(d);
form1.d.value=mul;
}

</script>
```

up is a function name with which i am trying to update the value of field(field name=d).
But its not working. plz somebody help me.

Comment: may be its document.form1.d.value = mul; ?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What does your HTML look like? Can you edit your question and add these details?

Comment: what calls this function, and what is the HTML for the form?

Answer (score 3):

You can handle it like so:

The HTML:

```
​<form method='post' action='doesnt_matter'>
<input type='text' name='field1' />
<input type='text' name='field2' />
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The JavaScript:

```
form = document.forms[0];
function up(d,mul)
{
    alert(d);
    form[d].value=mul;
}



up('field1','Hello field 1');
up('field2','Hello field 2');
​
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P3Dpw/)

Answer (score 2):

Well you pass `d` as parameter. So you either have to do (renaming it do `fieldname`):

```
function up(fieldname,mul)
{
    document.form1[fieldname].value=mul;
}
```

and calling it with  `up('d', 'newValue')`,

or let `d` be:

```
function up(mul)
{
    document.form1.d.value=mul;
}
```

Not sure if you need `document` but I think you do.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8uyv8/

Answer (score 0):

```
function up(d,mul) { alert(d); form1[d].value=mul; }
```

You can't use d literally here as it assumes you are looking for an element named "d". So you have to use d in a context where it will use it's value, in this case, an array index.